# Unable to Add in Intuit DataServices using .Add() method

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

i am using HelloIntuitAnywhere sample application to insert values into QuickBook online.

**Code:**

> OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new
>   OAuthRequestValidator(token, secret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
>
> ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, realmId,
>   intuitServiceType);
>
> DataServices commonService = new DataServices(context);
>
> Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer qboCustomer = new
>   Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Customer();
>
> qboCustomer.Name = "Test Name";
>
> qboCustomer.DBAName = "Test DBA";
>
> commonService.Add(qboCustomer);

**Error:**
There is an error in XML document (1, 1).

Comment: I don't see any XML being used here? Where is the code that throws the error?

Comment: Please enable logging and post the request/response XML.  http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0055_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/0600_Logging#section_10

Comment: I enabled logging and Request XML is:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<q1:Customer xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/qbo" xmlns:q1="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
 <q1:TypeOf>Person</q1:TypeOf>
 <q1:Name>Test Name</q1:Name>
 <q1:DBAName>Test DBA</q1:DBAName>
</q1:Customer>`

Response XML is:
`?      E?Kk?0?????5V?S)?B?:?C???\k??u???????a??U?9x??L.?V4?R ?>Y?8??{?&Z?S?V??Z???<??!A?????? ??z?]??q? ?${?????KKH???
????Qob?3TU?????????LT? ???&`
/????C%???9?]i?????[?z??J??jg
C/?f?\)?????O? Y<"`

Comment: Looks like your post was corrupted. Can you resend or add code to your original question?